# GROUP BY is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called **monitor_links** with the following columns:

[image: Image of my Table]

This table is used to store links from others websites. I'm getting those links using this query:

```
SELECT title, url
FROM monitor_links
WHERE id_domain = 5
GROUP BY url 
ORDER BY date_created asc
```

With that query I return the title and url from the storage link (where id_domain is equal to 5). But in my case, can exists rows with same **url**, and to not return same repeated **url** I'm using `GROUP BY url`. *(If exists more than one row with same URL and id_domain = 5, my code returns only one of this rows).*

The problem is that I'm getting the following error:

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'shuri.monitor_links.title' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by'.

Some people said that I can try to disable the `only_full_group_by`, but I want to fix my query rather than silencing the warning.

Comment: What happens if there are 2 entries with the same `url`, but different `title` values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: @AlexMcMillan Nothing... the query would ignore it

Comment: What is the point of the GROUP BY here? You're not grouping anything - there's no COUNT, no SUM, nothing which requires a GROUP BY. What are you attempting accomplish with this query?

Comment: @BobJarvis He's just trying to suppress multiple rows for the same URL.

Comment: @BobJarvis It's in the question: **to not return same repeated url I'm using GROUP BY url**

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`ANY_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) function to tell MySQL that you want to return any value within the group.

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(title) AS title, url
FROM monitor_links
WHERE id_domain = 5
GROUP BY url
```

This is essentially equivalent to turning off `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` temporarily for this query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one `title` for each `url`, then:

```
SELECT MAX(title) as title, url
FROM monitor_links
WHERE id_domain = 5
GROUP BY url ;
```

If you want the most recent version:

```
SELECT ml.*
FROM monitor_links ml
WHERE ml.created_date = (SELECT MAX(ml2.created_date)
                         FROM monitor_links ml2
                         WHERE ml2.url = ml.url AND ml2.id_domain = ml.id_domain
                        );
```